# Infix to postfix parser in java

Tags: java, math-expression-eval

Please review my `Parser` class. Should I declare map outside of `convToPosfixQueue` method?

```
class Parser {

    private final Stack<String> tempStack = new Stack<>();
    private final Queue<String> postfixQueue = new LinkedList<>();

    public Parser(Queue<String> infixQueue) {
        convToPosfixQueue(infixQueue);
    }

    public Parser() {
        super();
    }

    interface ProcessingMethod {
        void method(String token);
    }

    public Queue<String> convToPosfixQueue(Queue<String> infixQueue) {
        Map<String, ProcessingMethod> methodMap = new HashMap<>();
        methodMap.put("(", this::parseOpenBracket);
        methodMap.put(")", this::parseCloseBracket);
        methodMap.put("+", this::parseOperator);
        methodMap.put("-", this::parseOperator);
        methodMap.put("*", this::parseOperator);
        methodMap.put("/", this::parseOperator);

        infixQueue.stream().forEach(token -> {
            if (!isNumber(token)) {
                methodMap.get(token).method(token);
            } else
                parseNumber(token);
        });
         return collectParsedTokens();

    }

    private void parseOpenBracket(String token) {
        tempStack.push(token);
    }

    private void parseCloseBracket(String token) {
        while (!tempStack.empty()
                && !isOpenBracket(tempStack.lastElement())) {
            postfixQueue.add(tempStack.pop());
        }
        tempStack.pop();
    }

    private void parseNumber(String token) {
        postfixQueue.add(token);
    }

    private void parseOperator(String token) {
        while (!tempStack.empty()
                && isOperator(tempStack.lastElement())
                && getPrecedence(token) <= getPrecedence(tempStack.lastElement())) {
            postfixQueue.add(tempStack.pop());
        }
        tempStack.push(token);
    }

    private Queue<String> collectParsedTokens() {
        while (!tempStack.empty()) {
            postfixQueue.add(tempStack.pop());
        }
        return postfixQueue;
    }

    private boolean isNumber(String token) {
        return token.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");
    }

    private boolean isOpenBracket(String token) {
        return token.equals("(");
    }

    private boolean isCloseBracket(String token) {
        return token.equals(")");
    }

    private boolean isOperator(String token) {
        String OPERATORS = "+-*/";
        return OPERATORS.contains(token);
    }

    private byte getPrecedence(String token) {
        if (token.equals("+") || token.equals("-")) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Unfortunately I am at this moment down-voting this question because [I personally do not consider it a good question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562). With a few changes to your question, you can make it much more clearer and more interesting for reviewers. I am hoping to give you an upvote soon.

Answer (score 3):

#### Pointless call to `super()`

Calling `super()` when the superclass is `Object` is pointless:

> ```
> public Parser() {
>     super();
> }
> ```

You can safely remove that call.

#### Don't do work in the constructor

It's considered bad practice to do work in a constructor, as in this one:

> ```
> public Parser(Queue<String> infixQueue) {
>     convToPosfixQueue(infixQueue);
> }
> ```

Although you extracted the work to another method,
that doesn't change the fact that this class does all its work at construction time.

I suggest to remove this constructor, and let users start the parsing by explicitly calling the `convToPosfixQueue` method.

With this constructor removed, you can remove the other one too, as the empty parameterless constructor will be given by the compiler for free.

#### Hide implementation details

As the `ProcessingMethod` interface is implementation detail, it would be good to make it `private`:

```
private interface ProcessingMethod {
    void method(String token);
}
```

On closer look, I'm not sure it's really all that useful.
Its only purpose seems to be to serve as a switch when processing tokens.
I suggest to use a simple `switch` and let the compiler optimize that to a map if it wants to.

#### Using constants

`OPERATORS` inside `isOperator` is a constant, so it would be better to move that to a `private static final` variable.

#### Optimization for `methodMap`

You create a new `methodMap` every time `convToPosfixQueue` is called.
As the content of this map is always the same, it can be field, and initialized once at construction time:

```
private final Map<String, ProcessingMethod> methodMap = new HashMap<>();
{
    methodMap.put("(", this::parseOpenBracket);
    methodMap.put(")", this::parseCloseBracket);
    methodMap.put("+", this::parseOperator);
    methodMap.put("-", this::parseOperator);
    methodMap.put("*", this::parseOperator);
    methodMap.put("/", this::parseOperator);
}
```

#### Bug?

This class can be used only once, because after a call to `convToPosfixQueue` with non-empty input, `tempStack` and `postfixQueue` are not cleared. So when calling the method again, the parsed tokens from the previous call will still be there.

This can be fixed by clearing `tempStack` and `postfixQueue` as the first action of `convToPosfixQueue`.

#### Thread safety

The class is not thread-safe, as concurrent calls to `convToPosfixQueue` will manipulate the shared internal state. Perhaps thread-safety is not one of your design goals, but it's good to document this in JavaDoc.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all:** It's never a bad idea to explain what you want your code to do since it does help everyone involved. It often helps **understanding** a certain problem better by explaining it to other people, and the community on here will have a **much easier** time reviewing your code when knowing what your goal is.

Regarding your question: Reading the documentation about the tools that you're using can benefit you a lot, in this case [Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). In the documentation it says that the **left row** of the Map contains the key, which can not have any duplicates. Since you are using **String literals** as keys your map will always be **completely** overridden once your `convToPosfixQueue()` method gets called, thus making the generation of this map for every method call **unnecessary**.

It won't be that relevant if you're aiming to maximize your performance, but it is good practice.